# Double minus operation result

Tags: java

I have a stupid question :

```
String str0 = "245.00";
String str1 = "45.00";
Double str3 = Double.parseDouble(str0) - Double.parseDouble(str1); 
System.out.println(str3); =====> 200.0
```

Why it don't gives 200.00? (tested with Float too) And how to control number of digits after the comma?

Comment: If you want to retain a number of decimal digits, you should be using `BigDecimal`. If you want to just affect formatting, you can use `NumberFormat`.

Comment: There are no commas, only periods, dots, or decimal points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer but a general advice for doing floating point calculations.

You should use BigDecimal for calculations

```
public class BigDecimalExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

      //floating point calculation
      double amount1 = 2.15;
      double amount2 = 1.10;
      System.out.println("difference between 2.15 and 1.0 using double is: " + (amount1 - amount2));

      //Use BigDecimal for financial calculation
      BigDecimal amount3 = new BigDecimal("2.15");
      BigDecimal amount4 = new BigDecimal("1.10") ;
      System.out.println("difference between 2.15 and 1.0 using BigDecimal is: " + (amount3.subtract(amount4)));       
    }      
}
```

**Output:**

difference between 2.15 and 1.0 using double is: 1.0499999999999998

difference between 2.15 and 1.0 using BigDecmial is: 1.05

This answer is adapted from http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/java-mistake-1-using-float-and-double.html

Also you can read a very good article on the need for BigDecimal 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071332/the-need-for-bigdecimal.html

Answer (score 3):

To `.0` comes from the default implementation of Java `Double.toString()`.

To allow more control, use a `Format`. See here: [NumberFormat api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html%20NumberFormat%20api%20doc) and here [DecimalFormat tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html%20DecimalFormat)

For simple formatting, you can also use `String.format()`, for example:

```
String.format("%02d", myNumber)
```

Or even print it directly using `System.out.format`

```
System.out.format("%.2f", myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

When stored as a string, 10 is different than 10.0, which is also different than 10.00. When stored as a double, they may not be equal. Never trust two doubles to be `==`/`.equals()` the same.

To print a double with a certain number of decimal places, use the `printf` method. For example:

```
String str0 = "245.00";
String str1 = "45.00";
Double str3 = Double.parseDouble(str0) - Double.parseDouble(str1); 

System.out.println(str3);        // 200.0
System.out.printf("%.2f", str3); // 200.00
```

Comment: As a double, they're *exactly* equal. As a BigDecimal, they're not.